# wall switch burn out

Tags: electrical

Why does a 2 way light switch constantly burn out? I have replaced it twice but quits working after a few days.  I have to use the switch at the other end of the room to control the ceiling light fixture.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but it sounds like it's under some sort of unusual load; more details (and perhaps a picture) would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yea, in general, light switches don't break.  If they do, not twice in a row.  What _exactly_ does the switch control?  How many bulbs?  I assume this is a 3-way switch?  Are you using the screws to connect the wires?

Comment: "Burn out" and "quits working" are different things.  Are there signs of damage?  Are you sure some connection didn't simply pull loose?

Comment: So it's a 3-way switch if you can control the light from another switch.

Comment: Is this an electronic switch or a plain switch, can you link the product?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Maybe a fancy Alibaba switch.

Comment: What make and model is this switch, and what is the nature of the lighting load it's controlling?